# BeforeClose VBA Event Closing Workbook When Cancel = True

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a short macro that will prevent the user of an excel workbook from closing the workbook without protecting the first sheet.

The code shows the message box but then proceeds to close the workbook.  From my understanding, if the "Cancel" parameter is set to True, the workbook shouldn't close.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If Sheets(1).ProtectContents = True Then
        Cancel = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Please Protect 'Unique Futures' Worksheet Before Closing Workbook"
        Cancel = True
    End If    
End Sub
```

I just need the code to display the message box and then not close if the first sheet is not protected.

Comment: I've just tried Cancel = Not Sheets(1).ProtectContents and it works fine.  Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: Are you certain that the Worksheet at Index 1 actually points the sheet you are testing against? You can quickly test this using the Immediate Window in the VBE. (Press CTRL + G to open Immediate Window, then type `? Sheets(1).Name` )

Comment: I pasted your code into the ThisWorkbook module of a new workbook. When I tried to close it I got the message and the workbook remained open. So, it worked for me. I can't think of how you'd get the MsgBox but not have it Cancel.

Comment: That's strange, I also opened a new workbook and pasted the code and it still closed after displaying the message box.  It looks like the issue might not be with the code.

Comment: I copied only one line into a new / empty Excel file: `Cancel = False`. So, essentially, you can never close the file. When I tried to close it I got cancelled (as expected). Yet, if I immediately thereafter attempt (again) to close the file again then I can do so without the event firing up. Only if I do something between the two close attempts then it is firing the workbook close event again. Maybe there is something to prevent infinite loops?

Comment: I assume you mean `Cancel = True`?

Comment: If I paste `Cancel = True` into the ThisWorkbook module's Workbook_BeforeClose event, I can't close it no matter how many times I try. So, I can't reproduce what you commented on above. Perhaps you've got an addin running that's somehow messing with your events although, as I said in my first comment, hard to know how you'd only get half an event to run. Is this a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes it is a windows machine.  Are there certain add ins that have a reputation of messing things up?

Comment: Please also answer my question three comments up and confirm you meant to say `Cancel = True`. As to addins that mess things up, they are generally ones you wrote yourself :-). If you have any installed, you could try uninstalling them. Restarting Excel would also be good. If it was me I'd assume I've done something silly until proven otherwise. I wish I had more for you than that. One tip, when replying to a comment, do like "@DougGlancy" so that SO let's me know you replied.

Comment: @DougGlancy: yes, of course: `Cancel = True`. Sorry for the typo. Yet, I can sincerely say that there is no Add-On, modification, or anything special about my Excel setup. Just an ordinary Windows 7 64bit machine. Maybe it is something about Office 2016?

Comment: Nope, I've been testing with Office 2016. Seriously, it's very likely something unique to you and your computer.

Comment: @DougGlancy: now I got it. If I close the file with `Menu` --> `File` --> `Close` then I cannot close the file (as expected). The same happens when I use `Strg + F4`. Yet, when I close the file by closing Excel then the above occurs and the **second** press on "x" in the top right of Excel closes the application (and thereby the workbook) anyway.

Comment: Is the user protection unique? If not, just protect it with code. Or worst hack yet, have an `inputbox` that prompts for password then use that to protect.

Comment: Right you are! Thanks for showing me another reason to hate the `Before_Close` event :-). How about going at it from the other direction and protecting in the Workbook_Open event?

Comment: @DougGlancy: That is the work around solution I ended up going with.  The exact same code works under the Workbook_Open event.  It gives the same result (i.e. protecting the workbook before the next user can change things, but doesn't require any kind of saving before closing).  Thank you for your insights.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Thanks for the good question.

Comment: Just a question: Where is the need for it at the "closing/opening" point? can't you simply set the protection at `Workbook_BeforeSave`? (Makes more sense to me)

Comment: I want the worksheet to be protected any time the user is inside of it, unless the user unprotects it.  If the user doesn't save before closing (intentionally or unintentionally) I want the worksheet to be locked when another user opens it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could replicate it if I set `Application.EnableEvents` to `False`. In the below example I have remembered its state to place it back as was after, however, I'm not sure how it gets to a state of `False` to begin with.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim BlnEventState as Boolean

    BlnEventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Sheets(1).ProtectContents = True Then
        Cancel = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Please Protect 'Unique Futures' Worksheet Before Closing Workbook"
        Cancel = True
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = BlnEventState

End Sub
```

It may be a safer long term option to force the state rather then set it back.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Sheets(1).ProtectContents = True Then
        Cancel = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Please Protect 'Unique Futures' Worksheet Before Closing Workbook"
        Cancel = True
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2543601 Did this help?

Comment: Will the event `Workbook_BeforeClose` will even be triggered if `Application.EnableEvents` was set to `False` in the first place?

Comment: Also, how to revert any actions if Workbook Close event is cancelled?

Comment: Its been 4 years since I've been in this space, I'd recommend posting it as its own question if it doesn't exist or perform some testing to see what the outcomes are.