# initialize a workbook to open to the same sheet every time when opened

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook in excel that has an accumulating number of sheets. I understand the excel document will open to the last sheet you were on. But is their a way to make the workbook open to the same page every time? (it's ok if I need to use VBA) thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel's `Workbook_Open()` event fires too soon in the loading process for some methods or properties of the workbook itself to be reliably used.  Just activate the sheet that you want to return to in the `BeforeClose` event handler.

```
'In ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets("SheetWhatever").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, it works just how I wanted it to and it is nice to know workbook open doesn't always work.

Comment: @cfaidl05: for your consideration, the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event is neither reliable. It depends on how you close the file whether this event gets triggered or not: (1) close the file but not Excel, (2) close Excel using the `X` in the top right corner, (3) closing Excel using `Alt` + `F4` or (4) killing the Excel process in the task manager. Only for (1) and (2) the `_BeforeClose` event gets triggered each time. For (3) it gets triggered most of the time and for (4) never.

Comment: @Ralph - I doubt anybody expects anything to run after something has had it's process killed in the Task Manager.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness. Yet, you are of course right and to the most part I made this comment only because the event doesn't always get triggered when you close Excel (as stated above). We had a rather cumbersome scenario some time ago until we figured that one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896555/beforeclose-vba-event-closing-workbook-when-cancel-true (mostly in the comments).

Comment: @Ralph - I'm not sure what the relevance of setting `Cancel` to true is, but If you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: I did not include the above link because it is the same / duplicate but because (in the comments) you can see that different ways of closing a file may (or may not) trigger the closing event. `Cancel` was merely used to test this. All I am saying is that `Workbook_BeforeClose` is just as save as the `Workbook_Open` event. To be on the save side, I (personally) would probably implement both solutions together: activate the sheet before close and activating it when the file opens.

Comment: @Ralph - No, it actually isn't the same as the `Workbook_Open` event in the context of the answer. `Workbook_Open` isn't reliable because the workbook is in the process of opening, so indexing the `Worksheets` collection might throw a runtime error.  In `Workbook_BeforeClose`, that simply isn't going to happen.  If you do both of them, you'll still risk the runtime error - that's the entire ***point*** of not putting it in `Workbook_Open`.

Comment: Strange. I don't have a problem with the solution provided by @YowE3K. I guess that's why I don't get your **point** (same you didn't get my point about this solution not working when Excel is closed in a non-conforming way). Evidently, Excel is behaving differently for all of us most of the time and we should try to cover all loopholes (same as yesterday). So, thank you for continuously pointing out different Excel behaviors we should anticipate (even though we might not be able to reproduce them).

Comment: @Ralph - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775973/initialize-a-workbook-to-open-to-the-same-sheet-every-time-when-opened/38776237?noredirect=1#comment64923724_38776016

Answer (score 1):

Include a Workbook_Open event within the code module for ThisWorkBook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Instead of "Sheet1", use whichever sheet you want to activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: is there another method because its telling me that it has errors when opening the document and it's not working for me.

Comment: Are all the sheets "visible", or is the one you want to be shown when the workbook is opened currently "hidden"?

Comment: Yep, I made sure all the sheets are visible

Comment: Hmm, have you checked that you used the correct sheet name?  And what is the error that the code is giving you?

Comment: Ah - Comintern has just posted an answer pointing out that Workbook_Open sometimes fires too soon.  Try using Comintern's approach instead.

Comment: I was playing around more with your solution. I figured out that it wasn't working because it wasn't under the worksheet. thank you.